# In Inapp purchase, what if someone press the subscribe button and then the wifi gets disconnected at the same time

Tags: android, google-play

I have implemented an application containing InApp Purchase. I have tested and it works fine, the issue arises when someone presses the subscribe button and disconnects the wifi at the same time, the product gets subscribed and shows in play store but my serverside API is not getting the payment data. So, can anyone have any idea how to deal with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: theres a call back right? so upon success, theres a call back that you probably make a server call? what if you checked for internet connection in the call back. If there is, send it server, if there isnt, store in shared pref. on load of app again, check that flag, if its true, check internet, if its on, send the info you stored in shared pref to the server. have a call back, if it was successful, delete the shared pref.

Comment: @soldfor yes, I am implementing in the same way right now. Thanks.

Comment: cool, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

1. you can show "Cannot connect to network" error state in screen and when user press "Try again" resubmit request to your api.
2. You can also schedule a task in WorkManager and resubmit this information when internet will appear. For more info see: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

PS: you can check state of subscription with: 
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get